# How to set like value in query parameter with JPA named query

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I have a JPA query as below

```
 public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String> {
  @Query(value = "select * from User where code like 'PER%'", 
  nativeQuery= true)
  public List<User> findAllUsers(String param);
 }
```

How do I replace the 'PER%' with ?1

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String> {
  @Query(value = "select * from User where code like CONCAT(:param,'%')", 
  nativeQuery= true)
  public List<User> findAllUsers(@Param("param") String param);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the query parameter with index `?1` [Query Creation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) and [Spring Data JPA](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query)

```
@Query(value = "select * from User where code like ?1%", 
nativeQuery= true)
public List<User> findAllUsers(String param);
```

OR passing parameters via name.

```
@Query(value = "select * from User where code like :param%", 
nativeQuery= true)
public List<User> findAllUsers(@Param("param")  String param);
```